# Ошибка Cannot read property при работе с GMail API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, gmail

Не получается работать с GMail API. Каждый раз GMail не может быть прочитано и является пустым свойством. Я организовываюсь, могу пользоваться АПИ ютуба но не могу добиться использования апи гугла. Помогите пожалуйтса разобрать мою ошибку.

Код привожу:

```
var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyBnm60DnSJ2xVsRjo-L_9Mx_mALPy4ttUY'; 
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '435367929011-rutrvfe1hp1c85ra9a7vhnmtk3q72afa.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
];
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

  var GoogleAuth;
  var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl';
  function handleClientLoad() {
    // Load the API's client and auth2 modules.
    // Call the initClient function after the modules load.
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }

  function initClient() {
    // Retrieve the discovery document for version 3 of YouTube Data API.
    // In practice, your app can retrieve one or more discovery documents.
    var discoveryUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest';

    // Initialize the gapi.client object, which app uses to make API requests.
    // Get API key and client ID from API Console.
    // 'scope' field specifies space-delimited list of access scopes.
    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl],
        'clientId': OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPE
    }).then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
      var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
      setSigninStatus();

      // Call handleAuthClick function when user clicks on
      //      "Sign In/Authorize" button.
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').click(function() {
        handleAuthClick();
      }); 
      $('#revoke-access-button').click(function() {
        revokeAccess();      
      }); 
    });
  }

  function handleAuthClick() {
    if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
      // User is authorized and has clicked 'Sign out' button.
      GoogleAuth.signOut();
    } else {
      // User is not signed in. Start Google auth flow.
      GoogleAuth.signIn();
    }
  }

  function revokeAccess() {
    GoogleAuth.disconnect();
  }

  function setSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    var isAuthorized = user.hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE);
    if (isAuthorized) {
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign out');
      $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
      $('#auth-status').html('You are currently signed in and have granted ' +
          'access to this app.');
    } else {
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign In/Authorize');
      $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'none');
      $('#auth-status').html('You have not authorized this app or you are ' +
          'signed out.');
    }
    gapi.client.gmail.users;
  }

  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    setSigninStatus();
  }
  function gmailInit()
  {
    GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
      gapi.client.init({
          'discoveryDocs': ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"],
          'clientId': OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
          'scope': "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
          'apiKey': API_KEY
        }).then(function(){
          gapi.client.gmail.Users.getProfile({
            'userId': 'me'
          }).then(function(response) {
            var labels = response.result.labels;
            appendPre('Labels:');

            if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
              for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                var label = labels[i];
                appendPre(label.name)
              }
            } else {
              appendPre('No Labels found.');
            }
          });
        });

  }
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#gmail-init-button').on('click',function() {
    gmailInit();      
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас переменная `GoogleAuth` инициализируется в функции `initClient()`, но вызова этой функции нет.

```
$(function() {
  gapi.load('client', initClient);
  $('#gmail-init-button').on('click', function() {
    gmailInit();      
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Я попробую этот код и сразу отпишусь вам.

Comment: Извините. Та строчка осталась экспериментов. Поле GMail всегда пусто. В этом заключается проблема.

Comment: @иванганенко, приведите актуальный код.

Comment: Я решил вопрос. Помогло дополнение поля discoveryDocs. Теперь это выглядит так - 'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl, "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"]. Спасибо вам за ответ и так как вы один кто откликнулся то я помечу ваш как правельный.

Comment: Можно ли с вами поговорить в чате?

Comment: @иванганенко, да.

Comment: Ой, только что решился второй вопрос!) В общем спасибо вам за беспокойство) Чат уже не требуется.